# Volumes of solids of revolution around x- and y-axis

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, solid-of-revolution

What is the volume of the solid that results when the region under $y = 1 + x^3$ between x = 1 and x = 2 is revolved about the x- and y-axis?

For the x-axis:
$$ \int_1^2 \pi (1+x^3)^2 \,dx = \frac{373\pi}{14} $$

For the y-axis, I solved the equation in terms of y and I computed for the y-coordinates, so the volume is:
$$ \int_2^9 \pi [(y-1)^{\frac13}]^2 \,dx = \frac{93\pi}{5} $$

I only got 5/10 points in this problem, but I do not know which one is correct or wrong. Can you check these two answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your second one that is wrong: you need to integrate the region **under** $y=1+x^3$ so you'd be best served using the shells formula in that case.  But as you mentioned in the comments you can't use that formula.  That's okay, but now you'd need two integrals to get the answer.  First do the lower portion which is just the region $1 \leq x \leq 2$ and $0 \leq y \leq 2$:
$$
\int_0^2 \pi(2^2-1^2)dy = 6\pi.
$$
Your second region is between $y=1+x^3, y=2$, and $x=2$ so use washer formula:
$$
\int_2^9 (2^2 - (y-1)^{2/3})dy = \frac{47\pi}{5}.
$$

That then adds up to the same answer you'd get from shells (much easier): $77\pi/5$.

Comment: But the instruction is do not use shells, just disk and washers method. If I will use disk (or washer), what could be the solution instead?

Comment: Okay, I modified my answer.

Comment: Thanks for this! By the way, is there another solution for your first integral in which you will not integrate in terms of x but of y?

Comment: It actually should be $y$, that's my bad.  I'll change that.  By the way if you find my answer satisfactory then please accept it  : )

Comment: Ah, I see. What do you mean 'accept it'? I'm sorry, I'm not that well-versed yet here.

Comment: Ah, I see. What do you mean 'accept it'? I'm sorry, I'm not that well-versed yet here.

Comment: Ah, I see. What do you mean 'accept it'? I'm sorry, I'm not that well-versed yet here.

Comment: Haha no worries I'm a noob too!  If you ask a question and find someone's answer acceptable, then you should click the check-mark to the top left of their answer (near the number 1).  It helps our reputation and let's us do more things on stack-exchange.